# Foco no ultimo caracter Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, sweetalert

Preciso que quando o campo receba o foco, o cursor fique no ultimo caractere.
Da forma como está o cursor fica no início do campo mesmo que o campo não esteja vazio.

```
function gravaObs(unidadeObs) {
    var gasObs = $('#obsGas_'+unidadeObs).val();
    swal({
        title: "Inserir Observações", 
        html: '<input type="text" id="obsCampo'+unidadeObs+'" class="col-xs-12 form-control" value="'+gasObs+'" /><br>',    
        confirmButtonText: "Salvar",
        confirmButtonColor: "#5cb85c",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d9534f",
        showCancelButton: true,
        onOpen: function () {

            $('#obsCampo'+unidadeObs).focus();

            $('#obsCampo'+unidadeObs).on('focus', function() {
                var pos = this.value.length * 2;
                this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
            });
        }
    }).then(function(){
        var resultado = $('#obsCampo'+unidadeObs).val();
        console.log(resultado);
        $('#obsGas_'+unidadeObs).val(resultado);                
    }).catch(swal.noop); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa o `.setSelectionRange` e dá-lhe um numero maior que o comprimento do input.

Algo assim:

```js
$("#obsCampo").on('focus', function() {
  var pos = this.value.length * 2;
  this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $("#obsCampo").focus()
});

// ou de 3 em 3 segundos
setInterval(() => $("#obsCampo").focus(), 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="obsCampo" value="algum texto" />
<button>Clica aqui para focar o input</button>
```

Comment: Usando botao ele funciona mas como o foco chega no campo atraves de uma função nao funcionou.

Comment: @EzequielTavares deves estar a fazer algo errado. Dá uma olhada à resposta agora com um exemplo de função após 3 segundos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o codigo completo já com as alterações que testei.

Comment: conforme está ele recebe o foco atraves de uma função

Comment: @EzequielTavares com mais código agora percebo o teu problema melhor. Duas coisas: `1-` Estás a chamar o `.focus()` antes do auscultador de eventos: tem de ser ao contrário. `2-` Como esse input é criado dinamicamente tens de usar delegação. **Exemplo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/e4kv80pm/

Comment: perfeito sergio... funcionou redondinho inclusive no IE. abraço

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que receber o foco, seja por click, tecla TAB ou outro, o cursor estará posicionado após o último caractere:

```js
$("#obsCampo").on("focus click",function(){
 var pos = this.value.length+1;
 this.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="obsCampo" value="texto" />
```